# Key from one Json file to value of another Json file using node/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes

I tried and searched to make a JSON file who's keys are data in other JSON file
for eg:

**admin** in user.json is the key but it will act like value inside the Schema.json file
same other keys which are present inside the user.json file will act like value inside Schema.json file.

suppose I have `user.json` name Json file and in `user.json` file my keys are `admin, id, fname, lname, etc`
I want to make a another json with `schema.json` name where the keys which are present inside `user.json` are value of those `schema.json`

### user.json

```js
"addmin":{
  "id":"01",
  "fname":"tom",
  "lname":"jerry",
  "graduation":"PG",
  "address":"NYC",
  "job":"yes",
  "dreams":"travelling world"
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

image have a clear view what i want to achieve

[image]

I don't know how this gonna be done I tried by doing this but still not happening am getting the value from the file if I get key I can store it in `Schema.json`

```
 fs.readFile(
    "user.json",
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj.admin.id);
    }
  );
```

Comment: `user.json` is invalid? You will need curly braces around the `addmin property.

Comment: that `... ....` means more `[key]:[value]` @evolutionxbox

Comment: Sounds like a job for MongoDB, not JSON files... I mean you're basically defining a [Mongoose schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: @Vikas that doesn't make it more valid?

Comment: no @JeremyThille I have to make it in json format even I made this entry manually and there are lots of field in username so I can't make it manually one after another

Comment: Schemas don't really make sense in the context of javascript plus json. Perhaps you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you've defined the problem well enough yet, to be able to come up with a full solution.  But it might involve using the the Object.keys() function (documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to help you parse your JSON object.  To get you started, take a look at this:

```
fs.readFile(
    "user.json",
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      var schema = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
          return {
              uid: key,
              schema: Object.keys(obj[key]).map(function (itemKey) {
                  return {
                      uid: itemKey
                  }
              }),
          };
      };
    }
  );
```